# Creating a tabular data in latex

Tags: tables

I want to create a tabular data something of the sort in the figure. It's empty. But it has some contents filled. How can I do it in latex. It's like I have a row title and its contents inside the body.

[image]

Comment: @Christian Hupfer. It's just a list like you fill in a table row by row

Comment: @ChristianHupfer. By latex. I just have to write it. But kept it empty

Comment: @ChristianHupfer. I have updated

Comment: Silly question: The table has open lines at the top -- do the occure as a feature from the screen shot or on purpose?

Answer (score 3):

Since it is not clear how the table really looks like, I assumed some shape and dimensions. Change at will...

```
\documentclass{book}


\begin{document}


\begin{tabular}{|p{5cm}|p{5cm}|}
\hline
\textbf{Title 1} & \tabularnewline
\hline
Data 1 & \tabularnewline
Data 2 & \tabularnewline
Data 3 & \tabularnewline
Data 4 & \tabularnewline
\cline{2-2} 
Data 5 &  \tabularnewline
\cline{2-2} 
Data 6 &  \tabularnewline
Data 7 &  \tabularnewline
\cline{1-1} 
\textbf{Title 2} & \tabularnewline
\cline{1-1} 
More data 1 &  \tabularnewline
More data 2 &  \tabularnewline
More data 3 &  \tabularnewline
\cline{2-2} 
 & \tabularnewline
\cline{2-2} 
 & \tabularnewline
\cline{1-1}
\end{tabular}


\end{document}
```

[image]

**EDIT** Update after further request

```
\documentclass{book}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|*{3}{p{5cm}|}}
\hline
\textbf{Title 1} & & \tabularnewline
\hline
Data 1 & & \tabularnewline
Data 2 & & \tabularnewline
Data 3 & & \tabularnewline
Data 4 & & \tabularnewline
Data 5 & & \tabularnewline
Data 6 & & \tabularnewline
\cline{2-2} 
Data 7 & & \tabularnewline
\hline
\textbf{Title 2} & & \tabularnewline
\cline{1-1} \cline{3-3}
More data 1 & & \tabularnewline
More data 2 & & \tabularnewline
More data 3 & & \tabularnewline
More data 4 & & \tabularnewline
More data 5 & & \tabularnewline
\cline{2-3}
More data 6 & & \tabularnewline
\hline
 & & \tabularnewline

\cline{1-1} 

 & & \tabularnewline
 & & \tabularnewline
 & & \tabularnewline
 & & \tabularnewline
\cline{3-3}
 & & \tabularnewline
% Either one complete \hline or a single \cline{3-3} at the 3rd column 
%\hline
\cline{3-3}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

I still wonder about the layout of that table ...

[image]

Comment: Thanks But what if I have to create three columns. I am not able to modify it

Comment: Your initial screen shot did not show three columns. How should the third column look like?

Comment: I have updated the question

Comment: Does my other solution fit your needs?